# Why does USB drive auto-mount three times?

Tags: usb, automount

I am running Ubuntu 16.04 LTS with Mate.

When I insert a USB pen drive, it appears that the system attempts to mount the drive *three* times. I get three folders opening, and two error messages "Unable to mount 129 MB Volume Device /dev/sdd1 is already mounted at `/media/paul/2323-66A0'." (I guess the 1st attempt to mount is successful, hence no error emssage initially).

What process is triggering these auto-mounts, and where is it configured?

Apart from this issue the drive appears fine: I can move around the folder and un-mount as usual.

Update following the comments  below:

```
[496:~]$ lsblk
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0 465.8G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0 964.8M  0 part 
├─sda2   8:2    0 455.1G  0 part /mnt/backup
└─sda3   8:3    0   9.8G  0 part [SWAP]
sdb      8:16   0  55.9G  0 disk 
└─sdb1   8:17   0  55.9G  0 part /
sdc      8:32   0   1.8T  0 disk 
├─sdc1   8:33   0 931.5G  0 part /home
└─sdc2   8:34   0 931.5G  0 part 
sdd      8:48   0 123.5M  0 disk 
└─sdd1   8:49   0 123.5M  0 part /media/paul/2323-66A0
loop0    7:0    0  83.7M  1 loop /snap/core/3440
loop1    7:1    0  83.8M  1 loop /snap/core/3604
loop2    7:2    0  83.1M  1 loop /snap/core/3247
loop3    7:3    0    83M  1 loop

[496:~]$ sudo parted -l
Model: ATA ST3500630A (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 500GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size    Type     File system     Flags
 1      32.3kB  1012MB  1012MB  primary
 2      1012MB  490GB   489GB   primary  reiserfs
 3      490GB   500GB   10.5GB  primary  linux-swap(v1)



Model: ATA OCZ-VERTEX2 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdb: 60.0GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size    Type     File system  Flags
 1      1049kB  60.0GB  60.0GB  primary  ext4         boot


Model: ATA ST2000DX002-2DV1 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdc: 2000GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: msdos
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size    Type     File system  Flags
 1      1049kB  1000GB  1000GB  primary  ext4
 2      1000GB  2000GB  1000GB  primary  ext4


Model: USB Flash Disk (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdd: 129MB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos
Disk Flags: 


Number  Start  End    Size   Type     File system  Flags
 1      512B   129MB  129MB  primary  fat32
```

The USB drive is of course `/dev/sdd`, with only 1 partition.

`journalctl --follow` gave:

```
Dec 11 17:41:26 larkfield kernel: usb 1-2: new high-speed USB device number 24 using ehci-pci
Dec 11 17:41:26 larkfield kernel: usb 1-2: New USB device found, idVendor=090c, idProduct=1000
Dec 11 17:41:26 larkfield kernel: usb 1-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
Dec 11 17:41:26 larkfield kernel: usb 1-2: Product: USB DISK
Dec 11 17:41:26 larkfield kernel: usb 1-2: Manufacturer: SMI Corporation
Dec 11 17:41:26 larkfield kernel: usb 1-2: SerialNumber: AA04012707524
Dec 11 17:41:26 larkfield kernel: usb-storage 1-2:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
Dec 11 17:41:26 larkfield kernel: scsi host31: usb-storage 1-2:1.0
Dec 11 17:41:26 larkfield mtp-probe[5367]: checking bus 1, device 24: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.7/usb1/1-2"
Dec 11 17:41:26 larkfield mtp-probe[5367]: bus: 1, device: 24 was not an MTP device
Dec 11 17:41:27 larkfield kernel: scsi 31:0:0:0: Direct-Access     USB      Flash Disk       1100 PQ: 0 ANSI: 0 CCS
Dec 11 17:41:27 larkfield kernel: sd 31:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg3 type 0
Dec 11 17:41:27 larkfield kernel: sd 31:0:0:0: [sdd] 252928 512-byte logical blocks: (129 MB/124 MiB)
Dec 11 17:41:27 larkfield kernel: sd 31:0:0:0: [sdd] Write Protect is off
Dec 11 17:41:27 larkfield kernel: sd 31:0:0:0: [sdd] Mode Sense: 43 00 00 00
Dec 11 17:41:27 larkfield kernel: sd 31:0:0:0: [sdd] No Caching mode page found
Dec 11 17:41:27 larkfield kernel: sd 31:0:0:0: [sdd] Assuming drive cache: write through
Dec 11 17:41:27 larkfield kernel:  sdd: sdd1
Dec 11 17:41:27 larkfield kernel: sd 31:0:0:0: [sdd] Attached SCSI disk
Dec 11 17:41:28 larkfield udisksd[2699]: Mounted /dev/sdd1 at /media/paul/2323-66A0 on behalf of uid 1000
```

Which doesn't look too unusual. It was then followed by:

```
Dec 11 17:41:28 larkfield gvfsd[2634]: ** (process:2743): WARNING **: send_infos_cb: No such interface 'org.gtk.vfs.Enumerator' on object at path /org/gtk/vfs/client/enumerator/2350 (g-dbus-error-quark, 19)
```

about 45 times, which does (but may not be related).

Comment: In a Terminal window, type `journalctl --follow`, then insert your USB drive. When the messages settle down `^C` and look at the log messages. Use `lsblk`, `sudo parted -l` to learn more. `man lsblk;man parted;man sudo`, of course.

Comment: Your flash may have three partitions. Some gift/vendor/customized flashes have non-standard partitioning. It would be really useful if you update post with output of `lsblk` and `sudo parted -l` as *waltinator* suggested.